# Python find location and size of non zero numbers

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have a dataframe which has the elements as:

```
1/2/2010 5:00   0
1/2/2010 6:00   0
1/2/2010 7:00   0
1/2/2010 8:00   0
1/2/2010 9:00   5
1/2/2010 10:00  0
1/2/2010 11:00  2
1/2/2010 12:00  51
1/2/2010 13:00  68
1/2/2010 14:00  58
1/2/2010 15:00  0
1/2/2010 16:00  0
1/2/2010 17:00  0
1/2/2010 18:00  60
1/2/2010 19:00  24
1/2/2010 20:00  24
1/2/2010 21:00  0
1/2/2010 22:00  0
```

I want to find the frequency of all non-zero number clusters and location of first non-zero element in that cluster.

For above array, I would like the answer as:

```
Location        NumOfInstances
1/2/2010 9:00   1
1/2/2010 11:00  4
1/2/2010 18:00  3
```

I am not sure how to do this. Even with a for loop this gets complicated real fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a series named `s`

### Pandas

```
m = s.eq(0)
g = m.cumsum()[~m]
g.groupby(g).transform('size').drop_duplicates()

2010-01-02 09:00:00    1
2010-01-02 11:00:00    4
2010-01-02 18:00:00    3
dtype: int64
```

---

### Numpy

experimental

```
m = s.values == 0
w = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.append(True, m)))
pd.Series(np.diff(w)[::2], s.index[w[::2]])

2010-01-02 09:00:00    1
2010-01-02 11:00:00    4
2010-01-02 18:00:00    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I never would have thought how elegant this answer is.